# What software could I use to remake this page and put it in my wordpress site? I included a gif and the URL

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am not sure but when I decided to remake this, I thought it would be interesting to see what the best way could be.  I know I could use Camtasia2019 but that would make it a video.  I could make it autoplay for desktop viewers and they might not notice but I'd love to do it with code.  I guess I could use Adobe Animate but I feel like that's unnecessary.  The site has buttons placed in "custom" areas that change the center contents.  So you aren't changing or loading a new page every time a button is clicked..  [actual site I'm cloning](https://www.we.co/?ref=footer-v2#we)
[image: l]